# How does Eclipse know that com.sun is a restricted API?

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

I'm using `ClassPath.getAllClasses` from `Guava` to find in runtime classes that implement a certain interface. When used with `rt.jar` it finds many classes from `sun.*` and similar packages and I'd like to filter them out.

I want to reuse the mechanism used by Eclipse and maybe other java compilers to warn about restricted API. Does this information reside JRE or hardcoded into Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular example. It may be hardcoded. But note that Java offers annotations like `@Deprecated` which can easily be analyzed, for example by using the **reflection API** of Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is stored in so-called **[Execution Environments](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments) profiles inside of Eclipse**.

Because these profiles are originally an OSGi thing (see [`Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment`](https://www.osgi.org/developer/specifications/reference/#ReferenceEEs)), the profiles are stored in the [*org.eclipse.osgi*](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi) plugin/bundle in `*.profile` files that each contains a whitelist of the accessible packages (`org.osgi.framework.system.packages`), e. g. here for [`JavaSE-1.8`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/JavaSE-1.8.profile#n11).

If you create a new Java project you can choose either

- an **execution environment JRE** which gives you **access restriction** errors for imports of e. g. `sun.*` packages or
- a **specific JRE without any access restriction** to JRE packages

After project creation the chosen JRE can be changed in ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, tab ***Libraries*** by selecting the JRE and clicking ***Edit...***.

In addition, since the [Java Platform Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/), introduced with Java 9, the JRE itself restricts access to some packages (and instead of the file `rt.jar` there is the file `modules`).