# Cannot import class in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I've installed Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) on my Windows Vista 32-bit system.

When creating a Java project I can

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.*;
```

without errors, but when I type

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.Application;
```

the import statement gets underlined.

Under the project's had Java build path I can see the entries:

> JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] JRE System Library
>
> [CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0]

No matter which one I click, the error won't go away.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the error displayed when the import is underlined ? Why use this old version of Eclipse (is this a requirement or can you try on a newest version) ? JavaFX is not include in default JRE, do you also have imported JavaFX Runtime to your environnement ? [have a look here may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156678/5914654)

Comment: I have an old Vista computer. How do I import JavaFX?

Answer (score 1):

`com.sun.javafx.application.Application` is part of the Java 8 system library but **not** of the ***JavaSE-1.8* execution environment** which is only a subset of the Java 8 system library (e. g. all `com.sun.*` sub-packages are excluded in the execution environments).

To get access to the whole system library, choose an ***Alternate JRE* instead of an *Execution Environment*** (in the *Java Build Path* select *JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] JRE System Library* and click *Edit...*).

As long as no class is used, `import com.sun.javafx.application.*;` is not an error but only an unused import statement.

See also [*How does Eclipse know that com.sun is a restricted API?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52018579/6505250)