# Eclipse Execution Environments location

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse

I have a question regarding the list appearing in Windows -> Preferences -> Execution Environments.

I have a big list of different Execution Envirnments and I would like to know where there are coming from ? Are they only from the jdk ?
I mean forinstance I have a list with JavaSE- 1.6 to 1.8 and JavaSE-9 to 13 and I would like to know if they appears only because they are all in jdk14 or maybe I have multiple version of the jdk and so I would like to remove them to clen this mess.

Thank you for your replies and sorry if I misunderstood something.

Regards

Comment: _Execution Envirnments_ are only profiles, not an installed JRE or JDK. See for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019047/6505250

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard list built-in to Eclipse.

It is actually defined using the `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.executionEnvironments` extension point with the standard list being defined by the `org.eclipse.jdt.launching` plug-in.

There is no support for removing entries.

If you are working on multiple project it is quite possible that you might want one project to work in the Java 8 environment will another project can use Java 14.